# subtraction of 2 sign and magnitude binary numbers in assembly (ex : 11110110 and 10101011)

Tags: assembly, signed-integer

how can I subtract 2 sign and magnitude binary numbers in assembly (ex : 11110110 and 10101011)

I used SAL then I don't know how to pick out the sign bit, when we shift to left, our signed bit is Carry Flag. then I should use JC or JS? or ...

Comment: You can just use `test` and then `js` to see if the sign bit is set. You can use `and` to mask it out to get the magnitude. Work from there.

Comment: sorry , could you pls do it for 11110110 and 10101011 subtraction in emulator for me?

Comment: they are both 8bit signed numbers, in sign & magnitude system.

Comment: You hinted that you might use `JC` or `JS`  — why not write out your own code?  You're almost there.  Of course, you may not use the "best" way but that is another matter.

Comment: What ISA are you writing this emulator on?  x86?  You can check if their signs are the same or different with `xor al, cl` to set SF in case that helps.  (of course `mov` to save a copy of the original.)